# Oracle Database XE21C Error 203 1297 after moving to another machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I'm using **Oracle Database XE21C** and I want to move the database to another PC as that one is going to become a server. To start/stop the database a made a bat file for each, that is starting/stopping the 4 services that it needs (**OracleOraDB21Home1MTSRecoveryService**, **OracleOraDB21Home1TNSListener**, **OracleServiceXE**, **OracleVssWriterXE**). I copied the folder of the db to the new PC (keeping the same structure, drive letter, folder location) and exported/imported those services (from **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services**), also I added into **System variables\Path** the location to **dbhomeXE\bin** folder. Now when I try to start those services on the new PC, I have 2 problems:

1. When I start the service **OracleOraDB21Home1MTSRecoveryService** I get: "**Error 203: The system could not find the enviroment option that was entered.**"
2. When I'm trying to start the other 3 services I get "**Error 1297: A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration.**"

Can someone help me with these two errors, or maybe the problem is that I can't move the database like I tried?

Comment: There are host-specific things in the registry; you can't just copy stuff over and expect it to work. You need to install the software properly on the new host, establish a new CDB, then use either RMAN or DataPump utilities to copy the PDB or a logical dump of the data respectively.

Comment: I was hopping it would work, but a part of me was sure that this was what I would end up having to do. Thanks.